# Problem setting state - Too many re-renders - Next.js/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, setstate

Code Sandbox for this problem linked below for better understanding of the problem.

I am having a problem setting my **mymoviegenreobjects** as my **mymoviegenreinfo** state in my useFetchMovieGenreResults hook [line 15 in the useFetchMovieGenreResults hook]. What I am looking to do is set the results of my fetch from another hook (whitch returns an object) into the state mentioned above. However, every time I am trying to setState I get the error.

Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

I am setting the state correctly (as shown below but I keep getting the above error)

```
  setMymoviegenreinfo(mymoviegenreobjects);
```

So my question is how do I set the state without running into the above mentioned error and also why is this error happening?

Code Sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-swirles-8gm148/

I commented out the problematic line of code in the codeSandbox so that it runs, but you can uncomment it and get the error I am referring to by uncommenting line 15 in the useFetchMovieGenreResults hook which is in the hooks folder.

Comment: In general, 1. don't put hook calls inside `if` blocks, they're only allowed in the top level of component functions 2. use a capital letter for functional components ("Genre" instead of "genre")

Answer (score 0):

You are `Fetching details from hook` then you are setting state as:

```
setMymoviegenreinfo(mymoviegenreobjects);
```

which triggers re-render.

Then component render again and it will fetch results again and then set state which will trigger re-render.

...and repeat again...

> PROBLEM: Setting state using `setMymoviegenreinfo` will trigger re-rendering. So you should only set state only if it is required.

To get rid of it all you have to do is set state in `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setMymoviegenreinfo(mymoviegenreobjects);
  }, [mymoviegenreobjects]);
```